# "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory" While Filling a DataTable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

Using ASP.NET 4.51 and VS 2013 I am getting the following error when attempting to Fill a datatable using a stored procedure.

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory
```

I have have traced the error to the following:

```
Using myDT As New DAL.mbr_MediaComments.usrsp_mbr_MediaComments_CommentorsDataTable
    Using myTA As New DAL.mbr_MediaCommentsTableAdapters.usrsp_mbr_MediaComments_CommentorsTableAdapter

        myTA.Fill(myDT, toMbrID, mediaID) <------System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Here is my stored procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrsp_mbr_MediaComments_Commentors] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@mbrID int = 0,
@mediaID bigint = 0

AS
BEGIN

    //my query code

END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem, the error was caused by the following:

The stored procedure had defined one of the parameters as **bigint**

It should have been **int** as was defined in the database table schema.

**I seems that passing an Integer value to a table adapter Stored Procedure expecting a Bigint causes an AccessViolationException error.**

I hope this information helps somebody else.

Comment: Converting between int and bigint shouldn't result with AccessViolationException!
There is a bigger problem around .Net 4.51 (comes along with VS2013 as well) Multiple users are experiencing similar errors in various code paths and reported to Microsoft; no resolution from them yet.

Comment: @user1898611 What makes you think this is anything other than what the OP found and fixed? Do you have a link of some kind? Note that fixing the data type actually _fixed_ the OP's problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem was completely fixed in this instance. The data type conversion was the cause of the error. I was using VS2013 and .net 4.51

Comment: thanks man, you saved my day. I had the same error, and solved followig your suggestion. (.net 4.5.1, vs 2013)